# PHP error: Expected different insert

Tags: php, mysql

I have some PHP code that inserts data into a database. When I echo the table it has inserted the id instead of the category which is in the dropdown list.

The PHP code for the dropdown is:

```
<select name='category' id=category class="text">
     <option value='' name='option' selected>Select one</option>
<?Php
   require "config.php";// connection to database 
   $sql="select * from category ORDER BY `cat_id` ASC"; // Query to collect data 

   foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row) {
   echo "<option value=$row[cat_id]>$row[category]</option>";
   }
?>
</select>
```

The PHP code for inserting values is:

```
<?Php

    $for= $_GET['category']; //Take the value.
    $request= $_GET['option']; //Take the value.

 myquery="INSERT INTO request (`request for category`, `request`) VALUES ('$for','$request')";
 $query = mysql_query($myquery);
```

Comment: Please avoid using `mysql_*` extensions!

Comment: Thanks for the advice Thamilan.

Comment: If you want to insert the `category` and not the `id`, then you need to put the `category` as the value - `echo "<option value=$row[category]>$row[category]</option>";` as `$_GET['category']` gets the selected option value.

Comment: Post your error message and connection too!]

Comment: Also, `$_GET['option']` does not work for `<option value='' name='option' selected>Select one</option>` as only the `<select>` name is sent when a form is submitted, not an `<option>` name.

Comment: There is no error user Saty.

Comment: It wrote error as I expected another insert value

Comment: Post your connection code too!!

Comment: In case your wondering where the activity on this question is coming from [Is it okay to ask for upvotes in a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323847/692942)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the name of your `<select>` field is `category`, so when it is submitted to your insert query, it will insert the `id` of that category.

So if you want to display the data from your `request` table instead of the ID, you can use `JOIN`.

```
SELECT a.category FROM request a LEFT JOIN category b ON a.request_for_category = b.cat_id
```

## Advice:

- Don't use spaces() for column names
- Use at least `*_real_escape_string()` or better yet, `prepared statement`
- Use `mysqli_*` instead of deprecated `mysql_*`

Comment: is this mysql or `mysqli`